# Sort by a Column While Maintaining Information in a Row

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, sorting

I had a previous question with lots of support and it solved my problem. The next issue I have is sorting the data while bringing the information in the corresponding row with it. A link to the previous question I asked, linked [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/126621/how-can-i-sort-a-data-range-in-google-sheets-based-on-an-data-range/126631#126631). This is what I need to do:

I need to take any information in here, the Promotions sheet:

[image]

and organize it all into here, the Enlisted sheet:

[image]

This is the code I have so far that organizes the ranks, but not the corresponding data:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(SORT({Promotions!A2:A, IF(Promotions!A2:A="", , VLOOKUP(Promotions!A2:A, {Promotions!L1:L, ROW(Promotions!L1:L)}, 2, 0))}, 2, 1), , 1))
```

Comment: I need to bring the information from A2:F in the first photo and order it by column A into the second sheet shown in the second photo. In the order, show in the first photo, L1:L

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Yup, give me one second.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19VHGXa5Kl0YTGccyVuAUHU0l1Lb2la2PUsy4MPFKev8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(INDEX(SORT({TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 SUBSTITUTE(Promotions!A2:F, " ", "♦")), , 50000)), IF(Promotions!A2:A="", , 
 VLOOKUP(Promotions!A2:A, {INDIRECT("Promotions!L1:L"&COUNTA(Promotions!L1:L)), 
 ROW(INDIRECT("Promotions!L1:L"&COUNTA(Promotions!L1:L)))}, 2, 0))}, 2, 1), , 1)," "),
 "♦", " "))
```

[image: 0]